# converting user input date (04 01 2014) to (4th January 2014)

Tags: python

I'm writing a program where the user will input 3 numbers the day month and year and it will output in the format 2nd January 2014. So far i have done this

```
 year =input("what year is it")
 month=int(input("what is the numerical value of the month"))
 day=input("what number day is it")
 if month == 1:
     January = str(month)
     if day == 1 or 21 or 31:
         print (day+"st January",year)
     elif day == 2 or 22:
         print (day+"nd January",year)
     elif day ==3 or 23:
         print (day+"rd January",year)
     elif day == 4 or 5 or 6 or 7 or 8 or 9 or 10 or 11 or 12 or 13 or 14 or 15 or 16 or 18 or 19 or 20 or 24 or 25 or 26 or 27 or 28 or 29 or 30:
         print (day+"th January",year)
```

the problem i have run into is that when i input a day such as 4 it will ouput as 4st January 2014.
I am using python 3 and have learnt for and while loops and also if statements if that helps

Answer (score 2):

Use the libraries and dictionaries, a good rule to remember is if you need more than two `if`s a dictionary might be better.

```
from datetime import date

ext_dir = {1:'st.', 2:'nd.', 3:'rd.',
    21:'st.', 22:'nd.', 23:'rd.',
    31:'st.' } # all the rest are th
# prompt for the year month day as numbers remember to int them

thedate = date(year, month, day)
ext = ext_dir.get(day, 'th.')
datestr = thedate.strftime('%%d%s %%M %%Y' % ext)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are running in to is that when you perform the check:

```
if day == 1 or 21 or 31:
```

operator precedence in python makes this statement act something like this:

```
if (day == 1) or (21) or (31):
```

and in python, like many other languages, non-null/non-zero values are "`true`", so you always evaluate to true in the first test. To fix this, modify the `if` statement, and all of the following  tests to look more like the following:

```
if (day == 1) or (day == 21) or (day == 31):
```

Comment: Or do `day in [1, 21, 31]`

Answer (score 0):

```
 year =input("what year is it")
 month=int(input("what is the numerical value of the month"))
 day=input("what number day is it")
 if month == 1:
     January = str(month)
     if day == 1 or day == 21 or day == 31:
         print (day+"st January",year)
     elif day == 2 or day == 22:
         print (day+"nd January",year)
     elif day ==3 or day == 23:
         print (day+"rd January",year)
     else:
         print (day+"th January",year)
```